# Multiple Histograms from Pandas DataFrame with overlay

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I've had the hardest time figuring this out. I have a dataframe with multiple categorical fields and I wish to plot them all as histograms with the target variable (Income) overlaid on each histogram. I had hoped to be able to use Pandas to do the histogram and just iterate over all the fields, but when I try just to plot Race and overlay Income the legend says None and I can't seem to get the Income to stack on one another.

Below is a sample dataframe similar to mine and the latest thing I have tried..

```
exampledf = {'Race': ['Black', 'White', 'Asian', 'White', 
                  'White', 'Asian', 'White', 'White', 
                  'White', 'Black', 'White', 'Asian'],
        'Income': ['>=50k', '>=50k', '>=50k', '>=50k',
                   '>=50k', '<50k', '<50k', '>=50k',
                   '>=50k', '>=50k', '<50k', '>=50k',],
        'Gender': ['M', 'F', 'F', 'F',
                   'M', 'M', 'M', 'M',
                   'M', 'M', 'M', 'M']}
exampledf =pd.DataFrame(exampledf)
exampledf.groupby(['Income','Race']).size().plot(x=exampledf['Race'], kind='bar', color=['r','b'], logy=False, legend=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer from James using pure pandas is likely what you're looking for, but I've been more and more turning to [altair](https://altair-viz.github.io/index.html) for visualization from DataFrames because of its amazing simplicity.

You can get something like what you want by just assigning your frame columns to dimensions in the chart:

```
from altair import Chart

Chart(exampledf).mark_bar(
).encode(
    y='Race',
    x='count(*)',
    color='Income'
)
```

[image]

or:

```
Chart(exampledf).mark_bar(
).encode(
    column='Race',
    y='count(*)',
    x='Income'
)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I agree. Altair is essentially a wrapper around Vega-lite, which in turn came from the same group that made Vega and D3, and they are very good at making plots look great.

Answer (score 2):

The way you are calling `plot` is not correct. You don't pass an `x` variable for a bar plot using pandas.  It will automatically use the index as for the x axis.  However, because you have a multi-index, it is probably not going to give you the chart you want.

To create a bar chart of race vs income, you need to have race as the index (rows), income as the columns, and the count as the values.  You don't want `groupby`, you want to pivot your data.  In this case, you want to use `.pivot_table`.

This will create a new dataframe with the index as race (the x-values for pandas `.plot`) and the different incomes as the the columns (the y-values for `.plot`).

```
pt = exampledf[['Race','Income']].pivot_table(index='Race', columns='Income', 
                                              aggfunc=len, fill_value=0) 
# output of pt:
# Income  <50k  >=50k
# Race
# Asian      1      2
# Black      0      2
# White      2      5

# make the plot
pt.plot.bar()
```

Here is the image using IPython.  The defaults using Jupyter Notebook look better.

[image]